# My Django CSS is hosted on Google Drive and only shows up on the Chrome browser. Is that normal?

Tags: html, css, django, google-chrome, cross-browser

This link is in the header of my base.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B343XFIY55_lTUxJWk5YMEVzT1E">
```

The stylesheet only works when the website is accessed through Chrome. The web page appears without any styling whatsoever on Firefox and IE. Does Drive hosted CSS only work on Chrome? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I could load the css file from Firefox as well. May be the other browsers are not just happy with the content, they also want proper mime type and a .css file name?

Comment: @masnun if that's the case then I suppose it must be a problem with the way my Django app/Apache server is set up

Comment: How you run your django app? use build-in wsgi or other tools?

Comment: @Aison I use the wsgi